# Python-How to get the value from tkinter widget and assign it to a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import pyodbc

root1 = tk.Tk()

label1 = tk.Label(root1, text='product A')
entry1 = tk.Entry(root1)

label1.pack(side = tk.TOP)
entry1.pack()
input1= StringVar()
input1.set(entry1.get())
print (input1)
```

This code is used to assign the value from the input textbox widget to a variable-Input1. However,the value I get is:PY_VAR0 instead of the text in Entry1.

I need to print the input text. Why is PY_VAR0 appearing?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting the value of the entry widget before the user has a chance to type anything, so it will always be the empty string.

If you wait to do the get until after the user enters something, your code will work fine as-is. Though, I don't see any reason to use a `StringVar` as it just adds an extra object that serves no real purpose. There's no reason to use a `StringVar` with an entry widget unless you need the extra features that a `StringVar` gets you -- namely, variable traces.

The reason you are seeing `PY_VAR0` is because you must use the `get` method to get the value out of an instance of `StringVar`. Change your statement to `print input1.get()`.

Answer (score 3):

To get the contents of a `StringVar` call `get()`:

```
input1.get()
```

Also, you should bind your `StringVar` to the `Entry` otherwise the `StringVar` won't change with the contents of the `Entry` widget:

```
entry1.config(textvariable=input1)
```

Or you can bind at construction:

```
input1 = StringVar()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root1, textvariable=input1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the value of a Tkinter variable, you must use the `.get()` method to retrieve it, as in

```
print(input1.get())
```

Otherwise, you are accessing the variable's name, which is what you're seeing.

When you have a StringVar (or other similar Tkinter variable), you can get the name of the variable by casting to a string, such as

```
my_string_variable_name = str(input1)
```

This is the easiest way to get the variable name if you didn't set it when creating the variable.  You can set a variable name as follows:

```
sv = tkinter.StringVar(name='Fred', value='Flintstone') # Note you can set a value, too!
```

Then

```
print(str(sv)) # which is what is happening when you say print(sv)
```

prints out 'Fred', and

```
print(sv.get())
```

prints out 'Flintstone'